# WURFL memory allocation fatal error

Tags: php, memory-leaks, wurfl

I was using WURFL just fine, then all of a sudden it's throwing this error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65484 bytes) in /var/wwwlibs/vnd/WURFL/lib/CustomDevice.php on line 118
```

I've found some stuff online about Tera-WURFL, but (afaik) I'm not using that, but just the downloaded version from [sourceforge](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/php_index.php).  Someone suggested updating the SimpleXML, but I'm just confused as to why WURFL's going over the top.

My wrapper class is as follows:

```
<?php
namespace vnd\WURFL;

use \WURFL_Configuration_InMemoryConfig;
use \WURFL_WURFLManagerFactory;
/**
 * File: WURFL_bootstrap.php
 * Sets up and readies the WURFL library for platform and browser detection.
 */
require_once 'WURFL/lib/Application.php';

// ----- WURFL constants ------ //
define('WURFL_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__).'/');

# Directories
define('WURFL_RESOURCES_DIR',     WURFL_ROOT.'resources/');
define('WURFL_PERSISTENCE_DIR', WURFL_RESOURCES_DIR.'storage/persistence');
define('WURFL_CACHE_DIR',         WURFL_RESOURCES_DIR.'storage/cache');

class WURFLBootstrap extends WURFL_Configuration_InMemoryConfig {    
    const WURFL_WATCH_MODE = "performance";
    const WURFL_VERSION = '2.3.3';
    const WURFL_CACHE_EXP = 36000;

    # Our WURFL Manager
    private $_manager;

    # Our device where the capabilities lie
    private $_device;

    public function __construct(){
        $zipPath = $this->getPath();

        if(!is_file($zipPath))
            die($zipPath.' is not a valid file.');
        if(!is_dir(WURFL_PERSISTENCE_DIR) || !is_dir(WURFL_CACHE_DIR))
            die(WURFL_PERSISTENCE_DIR.' or '.WURFL_CACHE_DIR.' are not valid directories.');

        $this->wurflFile($zipPath);
        $this->matchMode(self::WURFL_WATCH_MODE);

        $this->persistence('file', array('dir' => WURFL_PERSISTENCE_DIR));
        $this->cache('file',        array('dir' => WURFL_CACHE_DIR, 'expiration' => self::WURFL_CACHE_EXP));

        // Automatically reload the WURFL data if it changes
        $this->allowReload(true);

        // Create a WURFL Manager Factory from the WURFL Configuration
        $wurflManagerFactory = new WURFL_WURFLManagerFactory($this);

        // Create our factory and start the process.
        $this->_device = $wurflManagerFactory->create()->getDeviceForHttpRequest($_SERVER);
    }
    /**
     * Returns the path to our ZIP file 
     */
    private function getPath(){
        return WURFL_RESOURCES_DIR.'/wurfl-'.self::WURFL_VERSION.'.zip';
    }
    /**
     * Seeing as this is a wrapper class, any calls to our $wflManager (or whatever
     * we happened to be assigned to) should be passed on to the actual
     * manager object where all the goodies lie.
     * 
     */
    public function __call($name, $arguments){
        //return $this->device->$name($arguments);
    }
    public function getDevice(){
        return $this->_device;
    }
}
```

The computer this is running on is an old laptop, so it's not stocked on memory, but what gives?  I removed everything that could be causing an over-allocation of memory, but so far it seems like WURFL just doesn't want to run.

I also tried clearing my cache and persistence directories and running it again, but no dice.

One thing I'm thinking is to use the XML configuration class as opposed to the `WURFL_Configuration_InMemoryConfig` (based on the name I assume it's storing everything in memory, at least temporarily, hence the crash), but I'm curious why it's all of a sudden throwing this error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with that library, but in general, you can find out exactly where things go wrong by [registering a shutdown function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) and printing the last error there.

Add the following piece of code somewhere at the start of your script (i.e. before the error occurs):

```
function my_shutdown_function() {
  echo "SHUTDOWN!\n";
  $err = error_get_last();
  if($err) {
    print_r($err);

    // optionally, if you want a stack trace:
    $ex = new Exception;
    print_r($ex->getTraceAsString());
  }
}

register_shutdown_function('my_shutdown_function');
```

You can have similar fun with [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and [`set_exception_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) if you like, although both of these will never catch a fatal error (among other failures).

Comment: Thanks for this snippet, I'm sure it'll come in handy sooner or later.  I think I was having some method name collisions... changing stuff around and doing a little optimizing got rid of it.  No idea though.